# Mapbox disable links inside popup Content

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, mapbox

I am including an iframe from an external resource (live webcams) and I was trying to remove the links inside the popup Content box that in this case contains an iframe.

**Here is the html that I am getting:**

```
<iframe>...</iframe>
    #document <!-- here is the content of the "hidden" iframe -->
    </iframe> <!-- greyed out in the js console-->
```

**Whenever I try to remove the iframe links:**

```
$('iframe').find('a') //[]
$('iframe').children() //[]
```

Do you guys have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You probably can't due to security reasons, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe